# How to show elevation on mouse hover in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, display

I've got a DEM layer and would like to have the status panel in the bottom display the elevation in addition to the mouse coordinate. Can that be done? Using QGIS 2.6.1

Comment: So it's not enough to have the height displayed in a dock widget like the [Value tool plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/) does?

Comment: Almost anything can be done, it's a matter of how much effort you're prepared to put in and if there's a plugin that already does it (or something similar). Do you have any python experience?

Comment: I'm new to GIS/QGIS and didn't know to look for something like that in the plug-ins.  I'll check it out.  I don't have any python experience with c#, and some other languages, so if doing it in python would be a fairly simple introductory experience, I'd be interested in doing that.

Comment: Rephrasing my first comment, have a look at the [Value tool plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/), you'll get elevation on mouse over from your DEM. Let me know if that works for you.